# Is SQLite database information still valid & is displayed on various phones if I run my app on different phones?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to local databases in Android & want to create a basic app using SQLite database .I have created apps using Fire store so I have an idea about login ,register ,sign out ,storing data , retrieving data , recycler views etc. which I have implemented successfully using Fire store

Suppose I want to create an app which lets user select their favorite color & display it on the screen. I also want to login/register user using SQLite. Now through Fire Store, I can do this very easily but had some basic doubts regarding SQLite.

I have logged in using SQLite , selected my favorite color & stored it in my SQLite database & it is being displayed on the screen. Now if I logout ( which I simply implemented by taking user to the login page on clicking the sign out button) & login again , will that color be visible on the screen again ? If I run this app on a new phone , will this color be visible & will my login credentials be valid on the new phone too or I'll have to register again?

Comment: They keyword is 'local databases', they are only local on your current phone. You can however save all the settings of an user in Firestore and retrieve these information with a succesful login to write the values into the local database.

Comment: So  it means the use of Fire store is compulsory to implement the feature that was I talking about  ?

Comment: given your circumstances yes. To say it simple, you need a way to save your settings somewhere, where you can associates settings with an account. This way the settings are linked to the account not to the phone